# System halts when i send 500 concurrent requests in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I have an excel spreadsheet with name and description and i want to create those in Salesforce. The sheet has 500 rows.
Through my app i send this to salesforce but it seems to always stop at about 98% .
Is that due to some maximum number of concurrent requests limit reached ?

Comment: Could be. Could be something else too. You've told us very little about your app, and "halts" is very vague.

Comment: i will expand on the app

Comment: how do you send them, 1 row per request? It'd be better if you bundle them, up to 200 rows in single network operation (with SOAP and "normal" REST API) or up to 10K in 1 operation when using bulk REST API. You might be hitting some API limits (check Setup->Company information). Do you at least reuse login / sesion id or is it 1 login and 1 insert per every row?

Comment: thanks @eyescream , After some detailed logging , the error was being swallowed. It was hitting api limits. thanks so much